# Ajax function always return a 0 and does not proceed further

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts2

I have the script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

     var xmlHttp=null;
    function GetXmlHttpObject()
    {

        try
        {
            // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
            xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            //Internet Explorer
            try
            {
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        }
        return xmlHttp;
    }
    function popSubCategory(){
        xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()
        if (xmlHttp==null)
        {
            alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request")
            return;
        }



        var url="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/populatePropertySubCategory.action";
          alert(url);


        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChangedmp();
        xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
    function stateChangedmp(){

        alert("Hello "+xmlHttp.readyState);
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
        alert("lk"+xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
</script>
```

And my `Action` method is

```
public String populatePropertySubCategory() {
        System.out.println("sub property called " );

        String errorXml = "This is a Sample to Check";

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        try {
            response.getWriter().write(errorXml);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return SUCCESS;

    }
```

my action support xml is

```
 <action name="populatePropertySubCategory" method="populatePropertySubCategory" class="PropActionSupport">
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
            <param name="excludeMethods">populatePropertySubCategory</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type="tiles" >
           submitProperty
            </result>
        </action>
```

Now when I called this code alert only 0 and does not print the response text.

I have already implement `ServletResonseAware` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try changing the javascript method from

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChangedmp();
```

to

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function myFun {stateChangedmp();}
```

Answer (score 0):

`class` attribute needs the full qualified name of the Class, including the package.

And you are using only one `Interceptor`, not all the stack plus the customized `Validation` interceptor;

change them to:

```
<action name="populatePropertySubCategory" 
        method="populatePropertySubCategory"
        class="org.foo.bar.PropActionSupport">

     <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
         <param name="validation.excludeMethods">
            populatePropertySubCategory
         </param>
     </interceptor-ref>

     <result name="success" type="tiles" >submitProperty</result>
</action>
```

P.S: this are the most obvious problems, but may be others in the javascript and in the result tiles part :&

Comment: Every thing is fine I just show the action method and method is called properly there is no issue with the method calling

Comment: You are calling the method *without* passing through the Default Interceptor Stack, the behaviour is unpredictable but not the one you want for sure...